# WPF Listview Binding XAML To Filestream?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

How Can I apply this approach to the newer XAML standard?

```
    public MainWindow() // setting my gridview in c# instead of XAML
    {
        var view = new GridView(); // 
        view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "Index", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Index"), Width = 37 });
        view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "Offset", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Offset"), Width = 50 });
        view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "Size", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Size"), Width = 50 });

        LV.View = view; // set the listview to the newly created GridView Settings
    }


Public Struct File_Data
{
 Int32 offset;
 Int32 size;
}


Public Class Input_Output
{
   File_Data[] FDATA = new File_Data[10]; // usually resize these by needed length later


void Read_File(string FP, Listview LV)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < FDATA.Length; i++)
    {
       FDATA[i].offset = BinaryReader.ReadInt32(); 
       FDATA[i].size = BinaryReader.ReadInt32();
       LV.Items.Add(new { Index = i.ToString(), Offset = FDATA[i].offset.ToString(), Size = FDATA[i].size.ToString()});
    }      
}

}
```

I know the filestream has not been opened or closed but I am just trying to keep my question simple,

Here is my  XAML way to setup the gridview columns opposed to setting them up in           MainWindow()

```
 <ListView x:Name="RDT_LV" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="454" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213">
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="Templ">
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Index"  Width="37"  HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource Templ}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Offset" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Offset}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource Templ}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Size" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource Templ}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Chunk ID" Width="65" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Chunk ID}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource Templ}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Why would i even bother declaring the columns in XAML at all in this case? I Don't understand how to bind the xaml to my filestream?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Load a UI from an external .xaml file?

Comment: Well my C# code I pretty much already achieved my goal, I just want to know what is the XAML equivalent, I am reading binary data from a file and dumping it to a listview, I just want to how this would be achieved using XAML data binding .